# How do I determine the locations and strength of earthquakes using a fictional tectonic plate arrangement?

Tags: earth-like, natural-disasters, geophysics, earthquake

I've got a world that I made using a combination of star system and plate tectonics simulations via a variety of programs. I've used this to build plenty of overlays for my world map—plate boundaries, biomes, winds, ocean currents, and so on.

The problem I come to now is that I want to make a habitability overlay, so I want to factor in natural disasters. How can I tell if a place should experience earthquakes? How do I know how often they should experience them, and how strong they will be on average? If the quake is underwater, how do I know if there should be a tsunami?

Sorry if this is a common question. My google-fu is failing me on this one. I want this world to be as scientifically accurate as possible, not only for fun, but so if the stories here take off, I can pull out a 10-year-old map and be all "Actually, there was always a copper deposit there. This is because..." and then the binder comes out.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. What you are asking at the moment is a full immersion course in Earth Science, which is rather broad for our standards. It would work better if you focused on a single question which doesn't require writing a book to be answered. Check our [help] for more info.

Comment: I doubt this is something we could derive from first principles on Earth, let alone in a simulated world. There's just too much going on with earthquakes.

Comment: @L.Dutch I see. I was unaware that earthquakes are not fully understood by modern science. Geophysics isn't really my thing. I'm a sociologist. Thank you!

Comment: @MeeptheChangeling this uncertainty makes it easier to fit it into your story. It can be what you require. Maybe be cheeky and model it after the clash of some cultural groups and the resulting destruction. Can add some extra depth to a story, mirroring or accentuating some things.

Comment: I'm not sure that earthquakes and tsunamis actually lower the habitability of a region. Tsunamis have always been bad, but you can sense them coming by observing animals and nature and than getting to higher ground. Earthquakes are even less problematic, as simple, single story houses with lots of wood based construction are pretty resistant. So in the long run, it is more annoying than anything else. Unless it is a very big event, but those are extremely rare.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Predicting where and when an earthquake will occur is still beyond us. We know regions where earthquakes are more likely to occur than others, but that's about it.

Regarding tectonic plates, the boundaries between plates are the most likely locations were earthquakes will occur. There are three types of boundaries:

- [Convergent plate boundaries](https://www.nps.gov/subjects/geology/plate-tectonics-subduction-zones.htm), also known as subduction zones.
  These occur when once plate slides beneath another plate. Such a
  plate boundary occurs to the east of Japan, at the [Japan Trench](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japan_Trench), this is where the earthquake
  occurred that created the tsunami of 2011.  Earthquakes readily occur
  at these types of boundaries because the contact points between
  plates are not smooth, they are jagged. The jags catch and when they
  suddenly release an earthquake occurs.
- Strike Slip Faults are faults that move horizontally sideways
  relative to one another. The prime example of this type of fault is
  the [San Andreas Fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Andreas_Fault). As with convergent plate boundaries, the
  contact surfaces of strike slip faults are not smooth and they
  contain jags. When a jag point snaps and leases energy from
  obstructed motion an earthquake occurs.
- The third type of boundary is a tectonic rift. This is were two
  plates are moving away from another or one is splitting. The two best
  examples of this are the [East Africa Rift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_African_Rift) and the [mid Atlantic Ridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid-Atlantic_Ridge).
  Volcanic activity beneath the rift zone causes the plates to
  separate. As the plates do so, contact points break causing earth
  quakes.

Tectonic plates move at different speeds to each other, the friction between plates and the strength of jags also varies and this is why we still cannot predict when an earthquake will occur at these locations.

There is another type of earthquake that is even less predictable, [intraplate earthquakes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intraplate_earthquake). Tectonic plates are not uniform land masses, they are bits of earth crust that are joined together. They each contain faults and discontinuities within them. They also contain differing amounts of intraplate ground stresses.

Occasionally, the localized strength of intraplate stresses is strong enough to cause intraplate faults to open up or move, resulting in earth quakes.

These are all forms on natural earthquakes. Humans can induce earthquakes by excavating large caverns or voids in or very close to fault zones, as can occur with some mines. Earthquakes can also arise when excessive amounts of ground water are removed from aquifers. This can also result in significant land subsidence, as has occurred in California.

Predicting whether a tsunami will occur and how large it will be is not yet a well understood science. Tsunamis occur when a significant block of the sea bed beneath has moved or slumped. This generates a shock wave within the water. Tsumanis only become problematic when the depth of water decreases, near coastlines. To compensate, large tsumami waves are created.

Predicting when are large block of the sea bed will move or subside, how large the block of sea bed will be and how much energy it will give to the water is something we don't know. Hence the mystery surrounding tsunamis. Having a system of ocean bouys that measure water movements is how we determine if a tsunami will occur, how large it might be and where it might occur.

Answer (score 0):

## Granite Bubbles

As Fred adeptly points out, predicting earthquakes doesn't actually exist. If you have the plates mapped, then any area on the junctions can be a place to expect volcanos and earthquakes.

Tectonic plates can be thought of as soap bubbles floating on water. Granite is lighter than basalt, so it floats. Figure out where on your map the updrafts are. Continents will float away from those spots. The mid-Atlantic ridge is a primary example of what that looks like. It pushes the continents away from each other.

Figure out where on the map the downdrafts are. Those will be the subduction zones, where the granite will pile up. California is the chunks of granite that floated north from the South Pacific basin to scrape against the rest of the continent, trying to worm its way underneath it, pushing the San Andreas mountains upward. We joke about California breaking off into the Pacific, but it's actually headed north, trying to sneak underneath the continent.